# system_cpu_usage value much less than expected

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, visualvm, micrometer

I am monitoring a spring boot application in promethus with metrics generated by micrometer.
For CPU usage, there is metrics 'system_cpu_usage'.

I observe that its value is mostly under 1. Is it expected? Same application when monitored in VisualVM, CPU graph is always above 15 percent range.

Do I need to multiple the value by 100?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Micrometer system_cpu_usage is reported between 0.0-1.0 (1.0 being cpu completely occupied). Hence you need to multiple the value by 100 to get in percentage terms.

Comment: Where can I check what are the return units of a metric and what are possible values?